# Prevent Race condition with files

Tags: java, file, race-condition, file-descriptor

If I test if I have permissions on a file with e.g. `java.io.File#canRead()` and create a `FileOutputStream` after that, it is (as far as I know) possible, that another process (e.g. `chmod` or `mv`) modifies the permissions or renames the file, deletes it or switches it with another file.

For example, I want to only write something to the file if it is executeable.

In C, race conditions like that can be prevented using a `FileDescriptor`.

In Java, there is a `java.io.FileDescriptor` class but it seems that this class is only for synchronizing buffers and creating streams and I would need a `File*Stream` in order to get the `FileDescriptor`.

How is it possible to prevent this race condition e.g. with `FileDescriptor` or another mechanismus?

Or is `File` protected against this in some way?

Answer (score 2):

You can change your approach and use Java NIO API's `FileLock` class from package `java.nio.channels`. According to [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html):

> This file-locking API is intended to map directly to the native locking facility of the underlying operating system. Thus the locks held on a file should be visible to all programs that have access to the file, regardless of the language in which those programs are written.

```
private static FileChannel fc;
private static RandomAccessFile raFile;

public FileLockProcesser(final String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    raFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
}

public void lockedWrite(final String data) {
    fc = raFile.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = null;
    try (fc; raFile; FileLock fileLock = fc.tryLock()) {
        if (fileLock != null) {
            buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes());
            buffer.put(data.toString().getBytes());
            buffer.flip();

            while (buffer.hasRemaining())
                fc.write(buffer);
        }
    } catch (OverlappingFileLockException | IOException ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

To check for permissions, you can again use NIO API. Example:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filePath = args[0];  
    Path p = Paths.get(filePath);

    if (Files.notExists(p))
        throw new FileNotFoundException();

    if (Files.isWritable(p))
        ...

    if (Files.isReadable(p))
        ...

    if (Files.isExecutable(p))
        ...

}
```

Comment: `raFile` is a member variable, not a method. How can `fc=raFile()` work?

Comment: And how can I e.g. check for permissions?

Comment: @dan1st I fixed typo and provided additional information about file's permissions. However, *some people* believe that checking permissions manually is bad practice, and they prefer trying to perform operations on a file and catch exceptions

Comment: Is the `Path` save from race conditions?

Comment: @dan1st Implementations of this interface are immutable and safe for use by multiple concurrent threads according to official docs.

Comment: I mean save from race conditions with other non-concurrent processes.

Comment: And I e.g. want to read the file only if I can (or cannot) write/execute and I don't think, exception handling is suited for that case.

Comment: @dan1st you mean accessing files? Unfortunately, it is not safe from RC.

Comment: Yes, I want to e.g. access the file dependinding on other permissions. Anyways, this answer might not be completely correct for my answer and I will therefore not accept it but I will keep it upvoted :)